# difference between add_object_page and add_menu_page

Tags: functions, wp-admin, admin-menu, add-menu-page

According to [Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_object_page), the `add_object_page` "essentially does the exact same thing as `add_menu_page()` in case you're wondering".

So.... what *is* the difference between those two functions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's just a wrapper for `add_menu_page()` with one addition:

> It adds the menu page as absolutely last/to the bottom of the menu.